# Calculate width and height of rectangle containing given area and conforming to given ratio.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My algebra is so rusty, this should be an easy one!

The area of a rectangle is

$$A = W \times H$$

If you're given $A$ (say $150$) and a ratio of $W:H$ (say $3:2$) how can you calculate $W$ and $H$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right so  you have $W:H$ is $3:2$, which means $$150 = 3x \times 2x$$ So this is just a simple equation which you can solve for. That is $6x^{2}=150$ which says $x^{2} =25$ and hence $x =\sqrt{25}$ that is $x =5 $. So $W = 3 \times 5 =15 $ and $H= 2 \times 5 =10$ and you can see that they have ratio $3 : 2$.

Comment: X=5 (then you get 3x * 5x = 15x10 = 150) - but you're showing X = 5 srt 2 - is that correct?

Comment: @Ryan: Edited now. Sorry made a *egregious* mistake

Comment: Cheers - skool is coming back to me after many years ;) Got stuck with simplifying 3x X 2x => 3 X x X 2 X x => 6x X x => 6x^2. Also found this http://www.algebrahelp.com/calculators/equation/calc.do?equation=150%3D3x*2x&solvf=AUTO

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for an answer for the same question. It's just that the other posts are kind of too complicated for me. I see it this way:

If you have given a width $a$ and a height $b$ and you know the $\textsf{area}$. You want to stretch each side with a ***fixed ratio*** of $x$ until you get the final size of the area. So you stretch $a$ with $x$ and $b$ with $x$ equals the $\textsf{area}$.

$$\begin{align*}
(a\cdot x)\cdot(b\cdot x)&=\textsf{area}\\\\
(a\cdot b)\cdot x^2&=\textsf{area}\\\\
x^2&=\frac{\textsf{area}}{a\cdot b}\\\\
x&=\sqrt{\frac{\textsf{area}}{a\cdot b}}
\end{align*}$$
$x$ is the ratio you are stretching. So you can multiply $x$ by $a$ and $b$ to get the new size of $a$ or $b$.

Answer (score 5):

**Assume:**

1. $ratio = \frac{x}{y}$
2. $area = x \cdot y$

**So:**

$x = y \cdot ratio$

**Using substitution:**

$area = (y\cdot ratio) \cdot y$

$area = y^{2} \cdot ratio$

$\frac{area}{ratio} = y^{2}$

$\sqrt{\frac{area}{ratio}} = y$

**Now that you have y:**

$x = \frac{area}{y}$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\rm\displaystyle\ \ \frac{W}H = \frac{3}2\ \Rightarrow\ 2\:W = 3\:H\:,\ $ so $\rm\ 300 = 2\:W\:H = 3\:H\:H\ \Rightarrow\ H = \ldots $

Comment: Bill - your hint has flummoxed me! ;)

Comment: @Ryan: What don't you follow?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer in the form of a formula that can be "plopped" into Microsoft Excel (or similar apps) here's what worked for me:

---

Let's say you have three [named cells](https://support.office.com/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) in Excel:

1. **`oldX`** : the **current image width**
2. **`oldY`** : the **current image height**
3. **`desiredArea`** : the **desired area** (`x*y`) of the image after resizing.

   - For example, if you want the ***final area*** to be a ***scaled %*** of
     the *current area*  (**`areaScale`** eg., `0.5` for 50%),
     then **`desiredArea`** = `( oldX * oldY * areaScale )`.

---

...finally, you can calculate the new values for `Y`, then for `X`:

Formula for **`newY`** is `=FLOOR( SQRT( desiredArea / (oldX/oldY), 1)`

Formula for **`newX`** is `=FLOOR( (oldX * oldY) / newY, 1 )`

---

*(This was my reinterpretation of LucasY's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1335527/546590) above.)*